# Decreasing of the sum by percentage (subtraction of percentage) SQL

Tags: sql, percentage

Substraction of percentage

I have got a table where is one record. Table looks like:

```
cust_code, SUM
1          25
```

I need to calculate a subtraction like this.

```
cust_code, ID, SUM
1          1   25
1          2   23
1          3   21.16
1          4   19.47
1          5   17.91
1          6   16.48
1          7   15.16
1          8   13.95
.          .   .
.          .   .
.          .   .
1          15  7.78
```

where value of sum in record 2 is subtracted by 8% of record 1, 
value of sum in record 3 is subtracted by 8% of record 2,
value of sum in record 4 is subtracted by 8% of record 3, etc.
Max ID will be 15.

It should be single query, I can use any additional external table (containing for example simple counter from 0 to 15).

Best regards,
Volcano

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `25 * power(0.92, rowno-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS
 (SELECT cust_code, 1 AS id, sum FROM cust
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cust_code, id + 1, sum * 0.92 FROM cte WHERE id < 15)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY id;
```

```
cust_code   id          sum       
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           25.0      
1           2           23.0      
1           3           21.16     
1           4           19.4672   
1           5           17.909824 
1           6           16.4770380
1           7           15.1588750
1           8           13.9461650
1           9           12.8304718
1           10          11.8040340
1           11          10.8597113
1           12          9.99093444
1           13          9.19165969
1           14          8.45632691
1           15          7.77982076
```